# How to test observable which belongs to another service in angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

```
$loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

constructor(private authHttp: AuthenticatedHttp, private httpResponseHandlerService: HttpResponseHandlerService) {
    this.$loggedIn.next(!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.getToken()));
    if (this.$loggedIn.getValue()) {
      this.checkAuth().subscribe((response) => {
        if (!response) {
          this.logout();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

There is `$loggedIn` value which is observable and i need to create a stub value which should be `this.$loggedIn.next(true)` in my `.spec.ts`.

Comment: If you want `!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.getToken())` to evaluate to true spy on the `isTokenExpired` method of `jwtHelper` and return `false` from the spy.

Comment: I was trying to do reach $isloggedIn value from .spec.ts. I have stub service 
AuthServiceStub = {
      getDecodedToken() {
        return stubValue;
      },
      checkAuth() {
        return of(false)
      }
    } 
like this and i want to reach this value like functions.

Comment: I'd advocate using a spy to verify that the `isTokenExpired` is called with the expected value, but you could use a stub instead. However you have to stub the right class and method to get the mock true value, which you don't seem to be doing.

Comment: @BatuhanKeten Can you provide sample code for `component` and its `spec` file. That would provide you a quick solution for you and would be easy for me to provide exact solution

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I solved it with mocking all the class in my spec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could spy on `this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired()` in order to return the value you want for your test. The only gotcha you might have is that `this.jwtHelper` is a private member of your service class, so it won't be that easy to spy on. In that case, the test might be suggesting you to redesign your class by creating another private method:

```
private isTokenExpired(): boolean {
    return this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.getToken());
}
```

So then you can spy on that in your test:

```
spyOn(yourService, 'isTokenExpired').and.returnValue(false);
```